# What is the Specific Fuel Consumption of CFM56-7B24/26/27 engines?

Tags: jet-engine, fuel-systems

I think the title completely says what I need. I use FSX (Flight Simulator X) to simulate flights and while flying the B738 I saw that it consumes much more fuel than the estimated amount, which is calculated by the software. By doing some research in the airplane folder I figured out that the problem is because the wrong Specific Fuel Consumption (SFC) is  entered there. And by some research on the net I also found the type of engine that B738 uses. So, right now, I need to know the SFC of the CFM56-7B24/26/27 engine so that I can enter the correct value in FSX.

Comment: Does it vary by engine type installed? Rolls Royce, GE, Pratt & Whitney, etc? Or by the power setting used? Or the altitude that is used for level flight? I know the power setting and altitude sure affect my fuel burn in my little, by comparison, Lycoming O-360.

Comment: Related thread elsewhere: http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=750059

Answer (score 1):

SFC for [CFM56-7B](http://lucintel.com/Webinar-Dec-06-2012-Turbo-Fan-Aero-Engine-Market-Brief.pdf) is 0.5lb/lbf/hr. As an aside, the LeapX is 16% better at 0.42lb/lbf/hr.